# Differences between baseline trust of stranger across cultures

Tags: cross-cultural-psychology, sociology

When encountering a new person, does the baseline level of trust (thinking the new person is "good") and it's change as result of new evidence, vary across cultures?

I can imagine controlling for appearance and the act goodness, it would be possible to measure.

Comment: This seems related to High/Low Trust Societies, but I currently don't want to make time to dig deeper https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_trust_and_low_trust_societies